# How to make a thread wait for a notify for a specific time and execute code according to whether it received a notify or not?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to implement something which is a bit of a variation of UDP.

The server thread receives datagram packets, parses them, and passes them to the appropriate thread. If it receives a message, it replies with an acknowledgement and passes it to the ReceiveMessage Thread which prints it onscreen.

I have a SendMessage Thread and a ReceiveMessage thread.

I want the SendMessage thread to send a packet, and wait for an acknowledgement for a specific timeout period. I want to send a notify() to SendMessage, if the server receives an acknowledgement, and if it doesn't, I want the SendMessage thread to timeout and execute different code in both cases. How can I achieve this?

```
public class ListenThread extends Thread{

protected DatagramSocket socket = null;
protected Boolean on = true;
protected String id;
protected HashMap <String,Contact> people = null;
protected String user;


public ListenThread(String macadd, String user, HashMap <String, Contact> people) throws SocketException
{
    super("ListenThread");
    this.socket = new DatagramSocket(3333);
    this.id=macadd;
    this.people = people;
    this.user = user;
}

@Override
public void run()
{


    while (on) 
            {

                byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                try{
                        // receive request
                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                        socket.receive(packet);

                        String packdetails[] = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength()).split(":");//Important part of receiving request. Tool used to parse the request
                        InetAddress address = packet.getAddress();

                        if(packdetails[0].equals("D"))  // if it's a Detection Packet                   
                        {/* Handle what to do with Detection packets */
                            }// end of small if
                        }//end of big if
                        else if(packdetails[0].equals("M"))// implies, Message type packet
                        {
                            Timestamp t =new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
                            //Send Acknowledgement
                            String PString = new String("A:"+id);
                            buf = PString.getBytes();
                            packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, 3333);

                            new ReceiveMessage(packdetails, address, people, t).start();
                        }
                        else// if it's an acknowledgemnt
                        {
                            //notify the sendmessage thread
                        }
                    }//end of try
                    catch (UnknownHostException e) 
                    {
                        System.err.print("Unable to find IP of current machine");
                    }
                    catch (IOException except)
                    {
                        System.err.print("Network Problem : Unable to send packets!");
                    }
            }//end of while
    }//end of run
```

}//end of class

```
public class SendMessage extends Thread{
protected Contact person = null;
protected String Message = null;

public SendMessage(Contact person, String Message)
{
    this.person=person;
    this.Message= Message;
}
@Override
public void run()
{
    System.out.println(person.getusername()+": "+Message);
    try
    {
        person.SendMessage(Message);
        Thread.currentThread().wait(500);// If i get notify => received acknowledgement
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Unable to send message!");
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        System.err.print("Woken before receiving notify");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don’t invoke `wait` and `notify` an a `Thread`. These methods are defined on `Object` so you can use an arbitrary `Object` for your communication assuming you `synchronize` on it correctly. But don’t abuse the fact that `Thread` inherits these methods from `Object` unfortunately; that’s misleading. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: So I would need to pass that said arbitrary object to both the threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many to achieve this, You could opt for CountDownLatch or CyclicBarrier where the Sender thread would wait for the receiver to act on the barrier. Another alternative would be for the receiver thread to put the ack  message in a blockingQueue and the sender could consume the ack from the queue while waiting on it.

Comment: Given that there maybe many sender threads on wait, and I could identify which sender thread I received an ack for(from information in the ack), is there a way I could ensure that only that particular sender thread gets notified?

Comment: Are all the senders waiting for the same condition? Once notified the waiting thread need to check whether the condition is true otherwise continue waiting.

Comment: All the senders are waiting for their own acknowledgement.
Currently I'm trying to implement it using hashmaps, where the thread id is sent in the ack packet, to let us know which sender thread to activate. Currently I've tried the BlockingQueue HashMap with threadid as key, but BlockingQueue doesn't give me the option to execute different code based on whether it got something from the queue or whether it timed out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As i understand you got multiple senders and One receiver. In that case you could have a BlockingQueue per sender and the sender thread would  poll it's queue for a specified time for the ack. The receiver thread will need to add the ack to the right queue based on the sender. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I did that. it works now. I looked into the java docs function!
Btw, what is less costly, throwing an exception if it doesn't get an ack and catching it, or a simple if then else statement doing that?

Comment: throwing an Exception is expensive and prevents jvm from doing any optimisations. If it involves huge volumes of data then throwing exception for each message(no ack) doesn't make sense at all. You might want the sender to retry sending the message if no ack is received or just simply log the message.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Condition.await(timeout,...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) instead of `Object.wait()`

Comment: Is there any usable implementation of this interface? It does not seem that JRE offers one.

Comment: @Pavel Horal: see [`Lock.newCondition()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#newCondition()) and [`ReentrantLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)